# Vim plugin for different languages in one webfile

Tags: indentation, filetype-php

I have the annoying issue that I have a .php file with HTML, CSS, Javascript and PHP. I use Vim. But the autoindent is always messed up and only works for one language in the whole file. Is there a vim-plugin which detects what language I am writing (by looking at the `<style>`, `<script>`, and `<?php` tags maybe?) and indent in the right way with the right syntax color and stuff?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Vim syntax documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_44.html), you can define blocks of syntax:

```
syntax include @PHP syntax/php.vim
syntax include @CSS syntax/css.vim
syntax include @JS syntax/javascript.vim
syntax include @HTML syntax/html.vim
syntax region PHP  start=+<?php+ keepend end=+?>+  contains=@PHP
syntax region CSS  start=+<style>+ keepend end=+</style>+  contains=@PHP
syntax region JS  start=+<script>+ keepend end=+</script>+  contains=@PHP
syntax region HTML  start=+<html>+ keepend end=+</html>+  contains=@PHP
```